# how main() is thread if we not extends Thread or implements Runnable?

Tags: java

i know main() is  a thread, only because of cmd says. But i want to know how it can be a thread if we not extends **Thread** class or **implements** Runnable interface?

Comment: Compiler magic.

Comment: Bascially the JVM launches a thread for you before your application starts.  And that thread is likely created by the OS when the JVM starts up: so OS magic.

Comment: JVM launvhes thread called The main thread is the thread that starts your program, or simply which runs your public static void main(String... args) method.

Comment: Check this nice answer: [SO answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433094/912829) [When the main thread stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416018/when-does-the-main-thread-stop-in-java)

Comment: So, I think the key thing here is to familiarize yourself with the concept of a thread; it is a **unit of execution**. The program's main function starts in a thread that is implicitly created by the JVM because it must be executed in **a** thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the *JVM* starts, it creates a thread named ***main***. This thread representes the main thread entry and the whole application will execute on it unless you start new threads from this one.

The *main* thread will then lookup for the `static void main(String[])` within your entry class to execute it being your program entry point.

You should not then confuse the *main* thread and the `#main(String[])` method as they are totally separate things.

Answer (score 0):

All processes on most operating systems run as threads, so it is impossible for a Java main method not to be a thread.  Although it doesn't extend or implement the Thread class, it is still running as a thread under the visible code.