# What if you pass a no-arg in the Thread constructor and don't extend the Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

What is happening in the background if I do this:

```
class TestThread {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Thread t = new Thread();
         t.start();

         System.out.println(t.getName());
     }
}
```

I know that to create a new thread you must override the `run()` method by either extending the `Thread` class or by implementing the `Runnable` interface.

If we implement the `Runnable` interface we have to provide the target run method where the code which has to run concurrently is provided.

Also, If we do not override the `run()` method and do not extend the `Thread` or implement the `Runnable`, the `main()` thread will execute.

I would like to know as to what exactly will happen in the background when I execute the above code? Does the main have a `run()` method like other `Thread`s? Will this create a new `Thread` in addition to the `main` thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * If this thread was constructed using a separate
 * Runnable run object, then that
 * Runnable object's run method is called;
 * otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.
 * 
 * Subclasses of Thread should override this method.
 */
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Since you haven't set a `Runnable` target, nothing will happen.

> Does the main have a `run()` method like other `Thread`s?

Low-level API can be used for this purpose. They don't necessarily need to create a `Thread` instance to run a thread. Here is a good discussion: [How main thread created by Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432963/how-main-thread-created-by-java)

Comment: where did you find this definition of the run() method ?

Comment: @SalilJoshi, in JavaDocs

Answer (score 0):

The new thread is created, starts, executes an empty* method, and terminates.

*) not really empty:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it created in addition to the main thread. Also is there a run() method in main as well ?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of the run() method ?